# How to display a scrollable bar of image thumbnails using java swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Say I've got a few .jpg images, and I want to display their thumbnails in a horizontally scrollable section of a fixed size. What swing components should I use to accomplish this? I was thinking JLabels for each photo and some kind of pane/panel to display them, with a horizontal scrollbar attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably put the pictures in JLabels, and then the labels into a JPanel, and then the panel into a JScrollPane.

```
JLabel[] pics = // Put pictures into labels
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayoutManager(/* FlowLayout if the pics are the same size; GridLayout otherwise? */);
for (JLabel pic : pics) {
    panel.add(pic);
}
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
scroll.add(panel);
// Disable the vertical scrollbar
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Comment: While I like your idea, from memory, the `FlowLayout` doesn't wrap well, so all the images would appear in a line.  This may or may not be what the OP wants, just thought I'd point it out

Answer (score 3):

Use a JList with a custom renderer to display Icons (actually, the default renderer may even display Icons or text, I don't remember). The list can be configured to render objects horizontally.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: Yes, the `DefaultListCellRenderer` is based on a `JLabel` so it can display icons